# Three inline divs: how to make display all three inline OR three block (NOT 2 + 1)?

Tags: html, css

I have a case of three inline divs that should be displayed either inline or in column if they don't fit in their container. However, if container is not wide enough for them to fit inline while being not narrow enough for them to collapse into a single column, they are displayed like 2+1 (two inline on top of one).

How to force them to display either ALL inline, or ALL in one column, provided:

1. I want to avoid using media query.
2. Inner divs have fixed width in px.

CSS:

```
.container {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.narrow {
    width: 200px;
}

.medium {
    width: 400px;
}

.wide {
    width: 600px;
}

.element {
    width: 100px;
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #FF0000;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container narrow">
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
</div>

<div class="container medium">
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
</div>

<div class="container wide">
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
</div>
```

JS Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5wLeggy4/1/

Comment: Do you have a maximum-width for a container? You could use media query for that (but only if you know the maximum width)

Comment: how about putting your code in the question so other folks with the same or similar issue will always have access to it? I know the fiddle is there, but it's great to see it here as it won't disappear.

Comment: after spending ages on this, i do have to enquire as to whether javascript/jquery is an option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to do it without using media queries is using flexbox:

https://jsfiddle.net/5wLeggy4/3/

```css
.container {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    display: flex;
}

.narrow {
    width: 200px;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.medium {
    width: 400px;
    flex-direction: column;
}

.wide {
    width: 600px;
}

.element {
    width: 100px;
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: #FF0000;
    border-radius: 5px;
    flex-direction: row;
}
```

```html
<div class="container narrow">
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
</div>

<div class="container medium">
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
</div>

<div class="container wide">
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
  <div class="element"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using "display : block;" instead of "display:inline-block;".

https://jsfiddle.net/AnjuRaj/5wLeggy4/2/

So your element class should look like:

```
.element {
    width: 100px;
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
    display: block;
    background-color: #FF0000;
    border-radius: 5px;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

About the best i can come up with: https://jsfiddle.net/5wLeggy4/5/

```
<div class="container wide">
    <div class="one">
      <div class="element"></div>
    </div>    
    <div class="two">
      <div class="element"></div>
      <div class="element"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<style>
.container {
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}


.one {
  display:inline-block;
}
.two {
  width:67%;
  max-width:364px;
display:inline-block;
  }

.element {
    width: 100px;
    margin:20px;  
    padding: 20px;  
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #FF0000;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
</style>
```

The width property on .two causes the second two elements to drop down together. The max width on the .two div means they also cannot expand.

Annoyingly there is a single pixel width of screen where they can be together due to the overlap of the two rules. if .two is 364px exactly, the two elements within will display inline.